# Siteground Laravel Storage Linked but files in it are not accessible

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

I have uploaded Laravel Site to Siteground.
I configured it and it was working great.

After some changes, I again uploaded the site by deleting existing files and adding new ones except for two files.

.htaccess and .env

Then I linked storage again and the images are not accessible.
I tried to delete the link and link again and the same issue.
folder permissions are 755 and files at 644
I even tried to set permission to 777 but it didn't work.

here is htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php81 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

running PHP 8.1
inside public folder files are accessible.
only the linked storage folder is not accessible.

It gives 403 error.

I have uploaded the same site on another hosting and its working fine on that.